# JQuery класс. Определить наименование вызванного метода

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, классы

Здравствуйте уважаемые специалисты, помогите пожалуйста с вопросом по `JQuery`. Есть класс `actionAjax()` который отправляет `ajax` запрос на сервер, в нем несколько методов в которых формируются `url` и отправляемые данные `data`, как в начале самого класса в переменной `calledMethod` узнать который из методов был вызван. Вот упрощенный код:

```
function actionAjax() {

    //вот здесь выловить наименование вызванного метода, должно быть 'voteAnswer' 
    var calledMethod = 

    this.voteQuestion = function(questionID) { 
        url = ... ;
        data = ... ;
        this.ajaxSend();
    }

    this.voteAnswer = function(answerID) {
        url = ... ;
        data = ... ;
        this.ajaxSend();
    }

    this.ajaxSend = function() { $.ajax... }

}

var actionAjax = new actionAjax(); //инициализация класса

actionAjax.voteAnswer(21312); //вызов метода класса
```

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: В переменной `calledMethod` не может быть `'voteAnswer'`.

Comment: `actionAjax.voteAnswer(21312);` //вызов метода класса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.voteQuestion = function(questionID) { 
  calledMethod = 'voteQuestion';
  ...


this.voteAnswer = function(answerID) {
  calledMethod = 'voteAnswer';
  ...
```

Comment: Спасибо, а в самом классе узнать нельзя? Чтобы не повторяться.

Comment: @ИгорьСаламов Я не понимаю, что Вы хотите узнать. Узнать в конструкторе, какой метод будет вызван внешним кодом? Только если конструктор может предсказывать будущее.

Comment: Спасибо большое, буду знать.